# Deleting checked item from CheckListBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'd like to delete checked items from CheckListBox by cliicking TButton but I've found only how to delete selected item and it's not what I'm looking for. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 3):

This code will do what you want. Note that `CheckBoxList1.Items.Count` is decreasing by one every time an item is deleted. For this reason we're using `downto` instead of `do` in the for-loop.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  index: Integer;
begin
  CheckListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for index := (CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1) downto 0 do
      if (CheckListBox1.Checked[index]) then
        CheckListBox1.Items.Delete(index);
  finally
    CheckListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

The `CheckListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;` and `CheckListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;` statements ensure that the control doesn't repaint itself while we're processing its items.

Comment: Always protect `BeginUpdate`..`EndUpdate` with `try..finally`.

Comment: This code will never raise any exceptions so there is no need to bloat it with exception handling.

Comment: @fritten just because you haven't *seen* it raise an exception before doesn't mean it *can't* raise an exception. Because it actually *can*, ie if the OS runs into an error while operating on the underlying ListBox, or there is a memory allocation error (the `Checked[]` property getter *can* allocate memory), etc.  So, don't make *assumptions* about what *can* or *cannot* happen. Be safe and prepared to handle both conditions either way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The private property getter will only ever throw if the index is out of bounds. But I'm changing my answer anyway. Don't want to propagate unsafe coding patterns in the guise that they are benign.

Comment: @fritten "*The private property getter will only ever throw if the index is out of bounds*" - that is not the only condition that can raise an exception.

Comment: No, you're right. I can at least think of the possibility of getting an out of memory exception (on RAII-creating a lightweight control-local "singleton" no less). Out of curiosity, what other exceptions could I expect here? (Disregarding thread contention on GUI elements of course.)

Comment: Also keep in mind that the VCL, RTL, and OS may change in the future. Even if these lines of code cannot raise today (they can!), they might do so tomorrow. (For instance, if the next version of Delphi has a `TCheckListBox.Protected[Index: Integer]` property prohibiting an item from being deleted.) Being stuck in `BeginUpdate` mode is not fun at all. Not using `try..finally` is a bit like driving a car without wearing your seatbelt: most times nothing bad happens, but it is still a very bad idea. So I just prefer to use a `try..finally` block every time I do need a guarantee.

Comment: (Except that I every day see far more examples of buggy software than car accidents.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Any aversion toward proper exception handling is silly and misplaced here, I agree. But especially due to my responsibility of showing safe practices. Now, there IS a case for bending the rules, but that requires in-depth contextual knowledge and must be evaluated on a per case basis (and I failed to mentally separate the simple test-case scenario from arbitrary production).

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you need, try following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  count : Integer;
begin
  i:= 0;
  count :=   CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1;
  while i <= count  do
       if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] = true then
       begin
               CheckListBox1.Items.Delete(i);
               count := count - 1;
       end else i:=i+1;
end;
```

Of curse, there are better solutions, but it is ready to use for you.

Comment: Not wrong, but needlessly complicated. Also dislike the `= true` part. (And `count` should really be `high`.)

Comment: It is a solution not an  answer has been written in a minute, please feel free and edit it.